# Hiding verbatim material on beamer slide while saving the space

Tags: beamer, verbatim, minted, phantom, fragile

The bigger picture is the following: I want to have a minted environment hidden in the presentation but save the space and have it available in my notes.

So I created a command: `\newcommand{\hidden}[1]{\phantom{#1}}` to hide the text for the presentation and change it to `\newcommand{\hidden}[1]{#1}` to show it in my notes. The first command works fine as long as I do not use verbatim.

However the following minimal example produces an error:

```
LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

(using `verbatim` for the MWE to keep it simple, but ultimately I'd like to use minted)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\phantom{
    \begin{verbatim}
        a = 1e-3;
    \end{verbatim}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't use verbatim material as argument of a macro, this will always cause an error. Can you add a bit of context what you are trying to achieve? Do you want to uncover the verbatim material on future overlays?

Comment: If the guess about uncovering the listing is correct, you can avoid the problem by warping it into `\begin{visibleenv}<2-> .... \end{visibleenv}`

Comment: with notes, you mean the beamer `handout` mode or something else?

Comment: Not necessarily handout notes. Just the same presentation just with the fill-ins

Comment: You can't use verbatim material as argument of a macro, so this won't work. But you could create an environment which does this. Let me try something

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. The bigger picture is the following. I want to have a minted environment hidden in the presentation but save the space and available in my notes. So I created a command: `\newcommand{\hidden}[1]{\phantom{#1}}` to hide the text for the presentation and change it to `\newcommand{\hidden}[1]{#1}` to show it in my notes. The first command works fine as long as I do not use `verbatim`

Comment: An approximation can often be gained by entering the "phantom" text as `\texttt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom environment to hide the verbatim material while keeping the space:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\newenvironment{foo}{}{}
\newenvironment{foo}{\begin{uncoverenv}<0>}{\end{uncoverenv}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
text
\begin{foo}
    \begin{verbatim}
        a = 1e-3;
    \end{verbatim}
\end{foo}
text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How elegant! Thanks so much this works like a charm!

Comment: One could probably make this even more elegant by automating the creation of both versions without having to comment and uncomment the definition. The same techniques as shown in https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=583 should be applicable.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that is what I plan to do.